# Kernel panic not syncing : Attempted to kill init

Tags: kernel, rhel, kernel-panic

OEL 5.9 (Tikanga) 2.6.18-371.6.1.0.1.el5

On boot I get the following errors:

> ...
>
> exec of init (/sbin/init) failed!!!: No such file of directory
>
> Kernel panic - not syncing - Attempted to kill init!
>
> ...

After this I booted to the OEL 5.9 CD in recovery mode. I tried to chroot to `/mnt/sysimage` with the following error:

> chroot: cannot run '/bin/sh' : No such file or directory

If I cd to `/mnt/sysimage` all of my files are there in `/bin` and `/sbin` (all files appear to be OK permissions and else). I am even able to open a new shell env by executing `/mnt/sysimage/bin/sh` without any issue.